# Are there any simple, zippered "sleeve" cases for the iPod Touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, hardware-recommendation

I'm looking for a simple, zippered "sleeve" case for an iPod Touch (like a laptop sleeve, only smaller). I'm interesting in something styled like Case Logic's zippered digital camera cases, such as [this one](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Case+Logic+-+Case+for+Most+Compact+Digital+Cameras+-+Black/9215761.p?id=1218060486861&skuId=9215761) or [this one](http://www.caselogic.com/herringbone_universal_pocket/product_detail/index.cfm?modelid=150383&productid=10019182). Those would be perfect, except the Case Logic website warns that they are too small to fit an iPod Touch (by about half an inch). I've looked at Incase's offerings, too, but they don't sell anything like these.

I'm primarily interesting in protecting the iPod's screen while carrying it in a pants or jacket pocket. Many of the iPod cases I've found either don't cover the screen, or are, frankly, kind of ugly and gaudy.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at this one.

http://www.sfbags.com/products/iphone-cases/travelcase-iphone.php

I have a sleevecase from that same vendor for my MBP, and it's been great.

Comment: Thanks. I shouldn't've used "travel case". I meant something more along the lines of a laptop sleeve, but for an iPod -- just couldn't think of the term. I updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of different options around out there. Here's two I've found:

- [iHome NXT Protective Speaker Case for iPod](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001S0PWPO)
- [Carrying Case for Apple iPod Classic / Nano / Touch / iPhone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002NLXBCI)

And while you might not think of it, there are several possibilities [on Etsy](http://www.etsy.com/search_results.php?search_query=%28itouch+OR+ipod%29+zipper) as well. If you find one there that's close to what you want but not *quite* right, you can always ask the maker if they do custom work.